# i am getting an undefined index

Tags: php, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [It doesn't insert the values in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968242/it-doesnt-insert-the-values-in-the-database)

I have a Javascript below where it adds a question number ($qid) for each row in a table:

```
<script> 
    var qnum = 1;
    function insertQuestion(form) {  
        var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
        var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
        var $qid = $("<td class='qid'>" + qnum + "</td>");
        $tr.append($qid);
        $tbody.append($tr);     
        ++qnum;
        $("#questionNum").text(qnum);
    }
</script>
```

Form code below. The rows which adds the question numbers is suppose to go in the table below and it does add the table rows in the table below:

```
    <form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($action); ?>" method="post" >
        <h1><?php echo $_SESSION['id'] ?></h1>

<p>

<input id="addQuestionBtn" name="addQuestion" type="button" value="Add Question" onClick="insertQuestion(this.form)" />
</p>

        <table id="qandatbl" align="center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="qid">Question No</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
        <p>
            <input id="submitBtn" name="submitDetails" type="submit" value="Submit Details" />
        </p>
    </form>
```

The problem is though and this is my question, is that I want to add all the question numbers in the table rows into the database (1 question number per database row) in a database but this is not possible as that in the form, I do not have a 'name' attribute to can call on to $_POST the question numbers from the form into my INSERT VALUES code to be able to add those question numbers in the database. What I want to know is where can I put the 'name='insertqid'' so that I can call up on it in my query to then be able to INSERT the question numbers in the database? At the moment I am getting an undefine index: 'insertqid' in the query.

Below is the php INSERT VALUES code I currently have:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $username="xxx";
    $password="xxx";
    $database="xxx";

    mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

    mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

    $insertquestion = array();

    $insertquestion[] = "' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['insertqid'] ) . "'";

    $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (QuestionId) VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insertquestion) . ")";

    mysql_query($questionsql);

    mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: @Junhahna, it is kind of a duplicate but I fixed most of the problem in that previous question, but this is a different problem because I wanted to know where do I put the 'name' attribute to be able to insert question numbers into the database

Comment: I don't see where is the code that appends row to the table. How do you call `insertQuestion` method? In order to post something to the server with a form, you need `input` fields with `name` attribute. I don't see any (except submit button).

Comment: I have forgotten to add the 'Add Question' button in the form, this has been updated in the code above

Comment: @Kosta  the 'Add Question button' appends the rows into the table

Comment: As Kosta said, you need `input` tags to pass a value to the server-side script. You'll probably want to use inputs of type "hidden" for the question numbers, and probably with an array'd name, like `insertqid[]` (which indexes can be mapped to your question inputs' array'd names, like `insertqinput[]`). Also, there are things we can't understand with this code you posted: 1/ what is this omitted tag of id "questionNum" 2/ why don't we see any input tag for the questions you insert 3/ why do you pass the form object to `insertQuestion()` as it doesn't seem to use it

Comment: And 4/ why put always the _same_ `_POST['insertqid']` in an array, server-side ?

Comment: Hi, look guys I apologise for not correctly putting the code in, I have really tried my best to shorten the code so I don't show a huge amount of code, my actual code is actually 1116 lines long but I have really tried to shorten it so you can all understand. I'm sorry :). Any thanks for telling me about the hidden input tag, I did not think about that, I can use that to put in a input and put in a name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can add rows as follows, however you haven't shown how the questions are added. All you will get from this is a table with a series of numbered rows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var insertQuestion = (function () {
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  row.classname =  'optionAndAnswer';
  row.style.align = 'center';
  var cell = document.createElement('td');
  cell.className = 'qid';

  return function(id) {
    var tbody = document.getElementById(id).tBodies[0];
    var r = tbody.appendChild(row.cloneNode(false));
    var c = r.appendChild(cell.cloneNode(false));
    c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tbody.rows.length));
  }
}());

</script>

<form id="QandA" action="" >
  <p><input type="button" value="Add Question"
      onClick="insertQuestion('qandatbl')">
  <table id="qandatbl" align="center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="qid">Question No</thead>
  </table>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit Details">     
</form>
```